# glGetUniformIndices not returning correct index

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I am trying to learn how to use uniform buffer objects, reading the OpenGL Superbible 5. I have a uniform block in the my shader:

```
layout(std140) uniform SkeletonBlock  
{  
    vec3 position[64];  
    vec4 orientation[64];  
} Skeleton;
```

Now my code to grab the index is:

```
const GLchar* uniformNames[2] =
{
    "SkeletonBlock.position",
    "SkeletonBlock.orientation"
};

GLuint uniformIndex[2];
glGetUniformIndices(shaderProgram, 2, uniformNames, uniformIndex);
```

For some reason this call is giving me a really high index (4294967295, consistently) and I am not sure why. I feel like I am missing something obvious. OpenGL is reporting one active uniform block, which is correct, out a max allowed of 15. No error flags are active before or after this section of code either. Any suggestions where it could be going wrong?

Comment: what does `glGetError()` return?  That really high index is synonymous with `-1`, which makes me think OpenGL is trying to tell you something.

Comment: Before and after the call to glGetUniformIndices(), glGetError() returns no errors.

Comment: A location of -1 means that uniform doesn't exist in the shader.Are you using those uniforms anywhere in your actual shader? It's possible that the GLSL compiler is optimizing them away.

Comment: Yes, they're used to compute the final position of the vertex. Thanks for clarifying though, was not aware of that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want

```c
const GLchar* uniformNames[2] =
{
    "Skeleton.position",
    "Skeleton.orientation"
};
```

As the semantics of a C-style language (such as GLSL) have it, you are declaring a variable of type `uniform SkeletonBlock` named `Skeleton`. Hence, `"SkeletonBlock.position"` is of the form `<typename>.<member>`, where you want `<variable>.<member>`.

The OpenGL docs say that you will get a `GL_INVALID_INDEX` from `glGetUniformIndices()` when you give it a bad uniform name. It might be smart to check each of the returned indices against this. I would bet that `GL_INVALID_INDEX == -1`.

Also, this number 4294967295 is the unsigned interpretation of a 32-bit -1 (twos complement).

Comment: -1: This answer is wrong. I don't know how it got accepted. The first 2 sentences are wrong in 3 different ways.

Comment: Nicol Bolas, please explain how this answer is wrong so that I can make appropriate edits.

Comment: My answer pretty much explains everything that's wrong with it. And [the UBO page on the wiki covers it too](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object).

Comment: The code snippet I provided is based on the OpenGL Superbible chapter describing how to create and use a UBO. The uses glGetUniformBlockIndex but occurs later; after getting filling the UBO with data. scpayson's answer resolved my issue of not retrieving the correct information in order to fill the buffer with information. Is there a known issue with the Superbible chapter that I am unaware of? I would like to know the proper way of working with these.

Comment: @RyanK: You say that it is "based on" Superbible code. Well, what is the *actual* Superbible code it's based on? Because `glGetUniformIndices` doesn't help with uniform blocks. Not with using them. Not unless it's trying to get layout information, which is pointless since you're using `std140` layout.

Comment: It is Listing 11.32 in the 5th Edition. The code snippets used aren't part of any example programs that came with the book so I can't link you to it or anything, and likely the reason for me not knowing proper usage.

Comment: If this fixes your problem, it points to an error in the implementation. Paraphrasing Section 4.3.9 of the [GLSL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) (4.3.7 in older versions): within GLSL, names declared inside the block must be qualified by the instance name if an instance name is present, but outside GLSL, they must be qualified by the block name if an instance name is present. If no instance name is present, the member name suffices in or out of GLSL.

Answer (score 2):

```
layout(std140) uniform SkeletonBlock  
{  
    vec3 position[64];  
    vec4 orientation[64];  
} Skeleton;
```

Here is how this definition reads:

- There is a uniform block named `SkeletonBlock`.
- It contains an array of 64 `vec3`s called `position`, followed by an array of 64 `vec4`s called `orientation`.
- The name for all of its members is qualified in GLSL by the identifier `Skeleton`.

Note the last part. In GLSL, and ***only in GLSL***, the `position` array is identified by `Skeleton.position`. In C++, the array is identified by either `SkeletonBlock.position` or `SkeletonBlock.position[0]`. The point here is that [from C++ code you use the block name](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Interface_block_member_naming) `SkeletonBlock` as a prefix, not the instance name `Skeleton`.

The `SkeletonBlock` block has an index that can be queried with `glGetUniformBlockIndex` (note the use of the word "Block" and the lack of plurality on "Index"). The individual uniform members also have indices, but they are indices into the list of uniforms. And these variables must be named correctly. If the uniform block has an instance name, then the uniform block members must be prefixed by the *block name*, not the instance name.

If you're passing those names to the OpenGL function and not getting valid indices, then you likely have a driver bug.

Comment: According to [ARB_uniform_buffer_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_uniform_buffer_object.txt), members of a uniform block have indices: "Each active uniform, whether in a named uniform block or in the default block, is assigned an index when a program is linked." I believe these indices are what you would pass to glGetActiveUniformsiv in order to determine the members' buffer offsets, for example. Of course that isn't necessary if using the std140 layout.

Comment: @tgnottingham: Uniform block members have uniform indices but not *locations*.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably encounter this if the uniform block variable isn't referenced (i.e. used) in the shader's GLSL source code. The shader source code compiler will remove the variable from the shader altogether as an optimization. Then, when you call `glGetUniformIndices`, GL_INVALID_INDEX will be returned.